# Chart.js work fine in 3.3.2 but from version 3.4.0 not work

Tags: chart.js

In version 3.3.2, my basic chart provided by the "getting started" documentation works perfectly.

But in version 3.4.0 or more recent :
When I refresh my page, I get a JavaScript error message saying:
`chart.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: #<Set> is not a valid property name.`

I don't understand where this error is coming from, and I haven't found anything after several hours of searching everywhere. Note that my project includes Joomla 3.9, MooTools, and jQuery.
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciiHJ.jpg)

I tried to disable responsive mode but was unable to disable it.
I also tried to go down in version number, that's how I realized that in 3.3.2, chartjs works well in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project integrates MooTools on version 1.5, the problem is there.

Update MooTools to at least 1.6.0 and the problem will be resolved.